# I'm trying to upload multiple files using JobIntentService in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intentservice, jobintentservice

I'm trying to upload multiple files using JobIntentService in android. The files seem to get uploaded, but I'm unable to track progress in the progress bar. The progress bar stays at the same position during the whole upload process and it just doesn't go away even after I'm done with the upload. I've tried to modify an implementation that I found in https://androidwave.com/upload-files-to-server-using-service-in-android/ but it's getting me nowhere.

Here is my FileUploadService.java class :-

```
public class FileUploadService extends JobIntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "FileUploadService";
    private static final int JOB_ID = 102;
    NotificationHelper mNotificationHelper;
    Disposable mDisposable;
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_RETRY_ID = 2;
    private ArrayList<String> imagePaths;
    private static String token,folderId;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mNotificationHelper = new NotificationHelper(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleWork(@NonNull Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onHandleWork: ");
        imagePaths = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("mFilePath");
        if (imagePaths == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onHandleWork: Invalid file URI");
            return;
        }
        RetrofitFactory<BaseNetworkResponse> mRetrofitFactory = RetrofitFactory.getInstance();
        IRetrofitContract iRetrofitContract = mRetrofitFactory.getRetrofitContract(RetroUtils.APP_ENV);
        Flowable<Double>fileObservable = Flowable.create(new FlowableOnSubscribe<Double>() {
            @Override
            public void subscribe(FlowableEmitter<Double> e) throws Exception {
                iRetrofitContract.uploadImage(token,folderId,createMultipart(imagePaths,e)).blockingGet();
            }
        }, BackpressureStrategy.LATEST);

        mDisposable = fileObservable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Consumer<Double>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Double progress) throws Exception {
                        // call onProgress()
                        FileUploadService.this.onProgress(progress);
                    }
                }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                        // call onErrors() if error occurred during file upload
                        FileUploadService.this.onErrors(throwable);
                    }
                }, new Action() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() throws Exception {
                        // call onSuccess() while file upload successful
                        FileUploadService.this.onSuccess();
                    }
                });
    }

    private void onErrors(Throwable throwable) {
        /**
         * Error occurred in file uploading
         */
        Intent successIntent = new Intent("com.wave.ACTION_CLEAR_NOTIFICATION");
        successIntent.putExtra("notificationId", NOTIFICATION_ID);
        sendBroadcast(successIntent);


        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                0 /* Request code */, new Intent(this, StartCameraAndProcessImageActivity.class),
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        /**
         * Add retry action button in notification
         */
        Intent retryIntent = new Intent(this, RetryJobReceiver.class);
        retryIntent.putExtra("notificationId", NOTIFICATION_RETRY_ID);
        retryIntent.putExtra("mFilePath", imagePaths);
        retryIntent.setAction(ACTION_RETRY);

        /**
         * Add clear action button in notification
         */
        Intent clearIntent = new Intent(this, RetryJobReceiver.class);
        clearIntent.putExtra("notificationId", NOTIFICATION_RETRY_ID);
        clearIntent.putExtra("mFilePath", imagePaths);
        clearIntent.setAction(ACTION_CLEAR);

        PendingIntent retryPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, retryIntent, 0);
        PendingIntent clearPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, clearIntent, 0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = mNotificationHelper.getNotification(getString(R.string.error_upload_failed), getString(R.string.message_upload_failed), resultPendingIntent);
        // attached Retry action in notification
        mBuilder.addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_revert, getString(R.string.btn_retry_not), retryPendingIntent);
        // attached Cancel action in notification
        mBuilder.addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_revert, getString(R.string.btn_cancel_not), clearPendingIntent);
        // Notify notification
        mNotificationHelper.notify(NOTIFICATION_RETRY_ID, mBuilder);
    }

    /**
     * Send Broadcast to FileProgressReceiver with progress
     *
     * @param progress file uploading progress
     */
    private void onProgress(Double progress) {
        Intent progressIntent = new Intent(this, FileProgressReceiver.class);
        progressIntent.setAction("com.wave.ACTION_PROGRESS_NOTIFICATION");
        progressIntent.putExtra("notificationId", NOTIFICATION_ID);
        progressIntent.putExtra("progress", (int) (100 * progress));
        sendBroadcast(progressIntent);
    }

    private void onSuccess() {
        Intent successIntent = new Intent(this, FileProgressReceiver.class);
        successIntent.setAction("com.wave.ACTION_UPLOADED");
        successIntent.putExtra("notificationId", NOTIFICATION_ID);
        successIntent.putExtra("progress", 100);
        sendBroadcast(successIntent);
    }


    private List<MultipartBody.Part> createMultipart(ArrayList<String> imagePaths, FlowableEmitter<Double> e) {
        ArrayList<MultipartBody.Part> partArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0;i<imagePaths.size();i++){
            File file = new File(imagePaths.get(i));
            partArrayList.add(MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file[]",file.getName(),createCountingRequestBody(file,"image/*",e)));
        }
        return partArrayList;
    }

    private RequestBody createCountingRequestBody(File file, String mimeType, final FlowableEmitter<Double> emitter) {
        RequestBody requestBody = createRequestBodyFromFile(file, mimeType);
        return new CountingRequestBody(requestBody, new CountingRequestBody.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onRequestProgress(long bytesWritten, long contentLength) {
                double progress = (1.0 * bytesWritten) / contentLength;
                emitter.onNext(progress);
            }
        });
    }

    private RequestBody createRequestBodyFromFile(File file, String mimeType) {
        return RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(mimeType), file);
    }

    public static void enqueueWork(Context context, Intent intent, String t, String id) {
        enqueueWork(context, FileUploadService.class, JOB_ID, intent);
        token = t;
        folderId = id;
    }

    public static void enqueueWork(Context context, Intent intent) {
        enqueueWork(context, FileUploadService.class, JOB_ID, intent);
    }
}
```

FileProgressReceiver class :-

```
public class FileProgressReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "FileProgressReceiver";
    public static final String ACTION_CLEAR_NOTIFICATION = "com.wave.ACTION_CLEAR_NOTIFICATION";
    public static final String ACTION_PROGRESS_NOTIFICATION = "com.wave.ACTION_PROGRESS_NOTIFICATION";
    public static final String ACTION_UPLOADED = "com.wave.ACTION_UPLOADED";

    NotificationHelper mNotificationHelper;
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    NotificationCompat.Builder notification;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context mContext, Intent intent) {
        mNotificationHelper = new NotificationHelper(mContext);

        // Get notification id
        int notificationId = intent.getIntExtra("notificationId", 1);
        // Receive progress
        int progress = intent.getIntExtra("progress", 0);

        switch (Objects.requireNonNull(intent.getAction())) {
            case ACTION_PROGRESS_NOTIFICATION:
                notification = mNotificationHelper.getNotification(mContext.getString(R.string.uploading), mContext.getString(R.string.in_progress), progress);
                mNotificationHelper.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
                break;
            case ACTION_CLEAR_NOTIFICATION:
                mNotificationHelper.cancelNotification(notificationId);
                break;
            case ACTION_UPLOADED:
                Intent resultIntent = new Intent(mContext, StartCameraAndProcessImageActivity.class);
                PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext,
                        0 /* Request code */, resultIntent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                notification = mNotificationHelper.getNotification(mContext.getString(R.string.message_upload_success), mContext.getString(R.string.file_upload_successful), resultPendingIntent);
                mNotificationHelper.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

RetryJobReceiver class:-

```
public class RetryJobReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String ACTION_RETRY = "com.wave.ACTION_RETRY";
    public static final String ACTION_CLEAR = "com.wave.ACTION_CLEAR";
    NotificationHelper mNotificationHelper;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        /**
         * Handle notification user actions
         */
        mNotificationHelper = new NotificationHelper(context);
        int notificationId = intent.getIntExtra("notificationId", 0);
        ArrayList<String> filePath = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("mFilePath");
        switch (Objects.requireNonNull(intent.getAction())) {
            case ACTION_RETRY:
                mNotificationHelper.cancelNotification(notificationId);
                Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, FileUploadService.class);
                mIntent.putExtra("mFilePath", filePath);
                FileUploadService.enqueueWork(context, mIntent);
                break;
            case ACTION_CLEAR:
                mNotificationHelper.cancelNotification(notificationId);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

NotificationHelper Class:-

```
public class NotificationHelper extends ContextWrapper {
    private NotificationManager manager;
    public static final String WAVE_CHANNEL = "default";


    public NotificationHelper(Context mContext) {
        super(mContext);
        NotificationChannel mChannel = null;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            mChannel = new NotificationChannel(WAVE_CHANNEL,
                    getString(R.string.noti_channel_default), NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

            mChannel.setLightColor(Color.GREEN);
            mChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
            getManager().createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }
    }

    public NotificationCompat.Builder getNotification(String title, String body, int progress) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), WAVE_CHANNEL);
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(getSmallIcon());
        mBuilder.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorAccent));
        mBuilder.setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setOngoing(true)
                //.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
        mBuilder.setVibrate(new long[]{0L});
        mBuilder.setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
        mBuilder.setProgress(100, progress, false);
        if (progress == 100) {
            mBuilder.setProgress(0, 0, false);
            mBuilder.setContentText(body);
        }
        return mBuilder;
    }


    public NotificationCompat.Builder getNotification(String title, String body, PendingIntent resultPendingIntent) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), WAVE_CHANNEL);
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(getSmallIcon());
        mBuilder.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorAccent));
        mBuilder.setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
        mBuilder.setVibrate(new long[]{0L});
        mBuilder.setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);

        return mBuilder;
    }

    /**
     * Send a notification.
     *
     * @param id           The ID of the notification
     * @param notification The notification object
     */
    public void notify(int id, NotificationCompat.Builder notification) {
        getManager().notify(id, notification.build());
    }

    /**
     * Get the small icon for this app
     *
     * @return The small icon resource id
     */
    private int getSmallIcon() {
        return android.R.drawable.stat_notify_sync;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification manager.
     * <p>
     * Utility method as this helper works with it a lot.
     *
     * @return The system service NotificationManager
     */
    private NotificationManager getManager() {
        if (manager == null) {
            manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        }
        return manager;
    }

    public void cancelNotification(int notificationId) {
        getManager().cancel(notificationId);
    }
}
```

My API :-

```
@Multipart
    @POST("/uploadImage")
    Single<BaseNetworkResponse> uploadImage(@Header("Authorization") String token, @Header("fileId") String fileId, @Part List<MultipartBody.Part> file);
```